# How to convert a string into a BASH array?

Tags: arrays, bash

Given the following string, produced by [jsawk](https://github.com/micha/jsawk):

```
[123,456,789]
```

Is there an idiomatic way of converting this into an array in BASH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply convert punctuations to spaces.

```
string='[123,456,789]'
array=(${string//[^0-9]/ })
```

Answer (score 3):

Strip the brackets, then use `IFS` to split on commas before
populating the array with `read`.

```
foo="[123,456,789]"
IFS=, read -a list <<< "${foo:1:-1}"
```

This accommodates any comma-separated string.